What is the best approach to handle class instances in django application in a production environment?
I would like to consider 2 approaches. First, you could create a class and its instance in a class and inside views import the instance and call its methods. Second, you import the class and create instance of the class inside the view function when you handle a request. which one do you think is better. Also I am not saying about any class like , models, forms or serializer etc that are related to Django , but the ones I manually create for myself.
Approach 1: Create an instance at module level and import it
# utils.py
class Calc:
    def run(self):
        # perform calculations
        return result

calc_instance = Calc()

# views.py
from utils import calc_instance

def view_function(request):
    result = calc_instance.run()
    # rest of the view logic

Approach 2: Import the class and create an instance inside the view function
# utils.py
class Calc:
    def run(self):
        # perform calculations
        return result

# views.py
from utils import Calc

def view_function(request):
    calc_instance = Calc()
    result = calc_instance.run()
    # rest of the view logic

Also, I see Approach 1 creates a single instance that remains in memory for the lifetime of the process, at least in the development server.
So based on your experience, which approach would you suggest, or are both exhibits similar behaviour in production environment.

Its depends on the use case
Use case 1: if you are not keeping any data in instance (similar to your first approach) better to go with Class Methods.
Use case 2: Keeping data in object. Import the class and create the object in your view.py (similar to your second approach)
The answer boil down to whether you want to keep data with object, if yes choose second approach, otherwise first one is make more sense.
